# Raphael bug when hovering to fast

Tags: javascript, hover, raphael

The hover on my circle works like a charm unless you hover out (or over) the dot to quickly. Then the first path that was draw is erased to soon and the other element stay visible, while they shouls also disappear.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayreona/462U8/4/)

And the code:

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 600, 300);
var circle1 = paper.circle(200, 200, 8);
var anim = Raphael.animation({
    fill: "#0099ff",
    stroke: "#0099ff",
    "stroke-width": 12,
    "stroke-opacity": 0.5
}, 1000).repeat(Infinity);

var a = paper.path("M200 200");
var b = paper.path("M180 180");
var rect1 = paper.rect(30, 180, 150, 130);
rect1.attr({
    stroke: "none",
    fill: "#ccc",
    "fill-opacity": 0.5
});
rect1.hide();

var attr = {
    fill: "#454545",
    "text-anchor": "start",
    "font-size": 16
};
var text1 = paper.text(40, 230, "Lorem ipsum dolor \nsit amet, consectetur \nadipiscing elit. \nMauris quis aliquam \ndiam.").attr(attr);
text1.hide();

circle1.animate(anim);

hoverArea1 = paper.circle(200, 200, 10);
hoverArea1.attr({
    stroke: "none",
    fill: "#f00",
        "fill-opacity": 0
});

hoverArea1.hover(function () {
    hoverArea1.node.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    a.animate({
        path: "M200 200 L180 180"
    }, 100, function () {
        b.animate({
            path: "M180 180 L30 180"
        }, 500, function () {
            rect1.show();
            text1.show();
        });
    });
}, function () {
    text1.hide();
    rect1.hide();
    b.animate({
        path: "M180 180 L180 180"
    }, 500, function () {
        a.animate({
            path: "M200 200 L200 200"
        }, 100);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are firing new animations before the previous ones finished. Raphael is trying to concurrently animate different end positions on the same element.
This is pretty easy to fix by stopping the current running animation immediately before firing the new one (this will stop it in place).
Just add `stop()` before you call `animate`.

```
b.stop().animate(...
```